# Capitalize first letter of each array element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace, char

I have a string of text that I've split into an array on each comma. I then looped through the array and added each element to a string, one by one, but separated them using a line break.

```
var beg2 = document.twocities.begins.value;
var ans22 = "";
var words2 = beg2.split(",");

for(var i=0; i<words2.length; i++){
    ans22 += words2[i] + "<br>"; 
}

document.getElementById("ans22").innerHTML = ans22;
```

Now I'm trying to capitalize the first letter of each line using this code but only the first letter of the entire string ends up getting capitalized as opposed to the first on each line.

```
var ans23 = "";

for (var i=0; i<words2.length; i++){
    firstLetter = words[i].charAt(0);
    firstLetterCap = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    words[i].replace(firstLetter,firstLetterCap);
    ans23 += words2[i] + "<br>"; 
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `replace()` does not change a string in place, you have to save the return value from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `.replace()`. Use `.charAt(0)` to selecting first character of string and use `.slice()` to selecting next part of string

```js
var beg2 = "first,second,third";
var ans22 = "";
var words = beg2.split(",");

for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++){
  words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1);
  ans22 += words[i] + "<br>"; 
}
document.getElementById("ans22").innerHTML = ans22;
```

```html
<div id="ans22"></div>
```

Also you can use CSS [`::first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) pseudo-element and [`text-transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) property to do this work.

```js
var str = "first,second,third";
document.getElementById("ans22").innerHTML = str.split(",").map(function(val){
  return "<div>"+val+"</div>"
}).join("");
```

```css
#ans22 div::first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div id="ans22"></div>
```

Comment: If you go the route of inserting each into a `<div>`, you also have the option to skip the `.toUpperCase()` and just use CSS: `#ans22::first-letter {text-transform:capitalize;}`

Comment: @ryantdecker Good mention. Added

Comment: There is no need to target the first letter. The capitalize property already does this. If you are targeting, use uppercase instead.

Comment: @JacobPariseau No, if string contain two word, `capitalize` consider first character of every word but OP need first character of every line

Answer (score 6):

You can simplify this considerably with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) by transforming each word in the sentence to its capitalized version and then joining the array back into a sentence:

```js
var sentence = 'hello world test';
var capitalized = sentence
                  .split(' ')
                  .map(w => w.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1))
                  .join('<br>');

console.log(capitalized);
```